# Add extra element using zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my code

```
    private $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','class'=>'blue-color','placement'=>'prepend')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),

    );
     public function init()
     {
      $username  = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username',array(
            'decorators'    =>$this->elementDecorators,
            'label'         =>'Username',
            'required'      =>true,
            'span'          =>array('class'=>'validation','id'=>'unameInfo'),

        ));
    }

       $this->addElements(array(
                        $username
        ));
        $this->setDecorators(array(
           'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag',
                array('tag'=>'table', 'width' => '100%')
                ),
               'Form'
        ));
```

Form created for above code is as below

```
   <tr>
       <td id="username-label"><label for="username" class="blue-color required">Username</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" span="Array"></td>
   </tr>
```

I want following html

```
<tr>
           <td id="username-label"><label for="username" class="blue-color required">Username</label></td>
           <td>
               <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" span="Array">
               <span class="validation" id="userinfo"></span>
           </td>
</tr>
```

How can i add span tag in my above zend form code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Write a decorator and add it to your element decorator list.

Comment: http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_form-decorators-explained/2010/02/

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
...
     $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(
                    'label' => 'Submit Button',
                    'class' => 'form-submit',
                    'decorators' => array(
                        'ViewHelper',
                    ),
                ));

        //$submit->removeDecorator('Label');
        $this->addElement($submit);

        $reset = new Zend_Form_Element_Reset('reset', array(
                    'label' => 'Reset Button',
                    'class' => 'form-reset',
                    'decorators' => array(
                        'ViewHelper',
                    ),
                ));
        //$submit->removeDecorator('Label');
        $this->addElement($reset);

        $this->addDisplayGroup(array('submit', 'reset',), 'submitButtons', array(
            'order' => 10,
            'decorators' => array(
                'FormElements',
                array(
                    array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),
                    array('tag' => 'td','class'=>'move_td')
                ),
                array(
                    array('row' => 'HtmlTag', 'class' => 'element'),
                    array('tag' => 'tr')
                )
            ),
        ));
...
```

This will generate code like below,

```
...
<td class="move_td">

<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Submit Button" id="submit" name="submit">

<input type="reset" class="form-reset" value="Reset Button" id="reset" name="reset">
</td>
...
```

**Updated**

Use below code to generate span

```
$this->addElement(
        'hidden',
        'dummy',
        array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore' => true,
            'autoInsertNotEmptyValidator' => false,
            'decorators' => array(
                array(
                    'HtmlTag', array(
                        'tag'  => 'span',
                        'id'   => 'span-id',
                        'class' => 'span-class'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
    $this->dummy->clearValidators();
```

Now you need to use addDisplayGroup function to group html elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want span tag instead of input type reset

Comment: How can I use this addDisplayGroup function with input type text and span? Can you explain this please?

Comment: @SwapnilTayade can you add class name next to requires inside addElement function pass array class name of both element to addDisplayGroup() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AnyMarkup](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62) decorator.

```
$username  = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username',array(
     'decorators'    => array(
        'ViewHelper',
         array('AnyMarkup', array('markup' => 'your-markup-here', 'placement' => 'append')),
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','class'=>'blue-color','placement'=>'prepend')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
     ),
    'label'    => 'Username',
    'required' => true,
    'span'     => array('class'=>'validation','id'=>'unameInfo'), 
    // actually, this last 'span' entry strikes me as odd
));
```

To add the decorator to an element using the short-form (as above) rather than creating an instance, you need to register the decorator's path/prefix with the element, something like:

```
$username->addPrefixPath('My_Decorator_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/My/Decorator', Zend_Form_Element::DECORATOR);
```

You can add that prefix/path to all (currently defined) elements using the:

```
$form->addElementPrefixPath($prefix, $path)
```

method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!! I am new in zend framework. So I dont know how to use 'markup'.

Comment: Create a file `library/My/Decorator/AnyMarkup.php` and past in the code from [here](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62). Then the code above should largely work.